# Extract IP from connection that listen and accept in socket programming in Linux in c

Tags: c, network-programming, sockets, ip

In the following code I would like to extract the IP address of the connected client after accepting an incoming connection. What should I do after the `accept()` to achieve it?

```
int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
portno = 8090;
clilen = 0;
pthread_t serverIn;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0)
{
    perror("ERROR opening socket");
}
bzero((char *) & serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) & serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr)) < 0)
{
    perror("ERROR on binding");
}

listen(sockfd, 5);
clilen = sizeof (cli_addr);
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) & cli_addr, &clilen);
```

Comment: You already have it in cli_addr, don't you?

Comment: @zneak I need IP for client that connect to me

Comment: yes, that is what `accept()` is giving back to you in `cli_addr`! You only need to format it - look at answers below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getpeername()`

See [the helpful description of how to use it over at the indispensable Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/syscalls.html#getpeername).

Comment: No need to call `getpeername()` as `accept()` fills in the client address into its second argument.

Comment: Beej's is a really nice intro.

Comment: (Apologize about mistakenly voting above comment as noise.)

Answer (score 12):

Your `cli_addr` already contains the IP address and port of the connected client after `accept()` returns successfully, in the same format as your `serv_addr` variable. Use [`inet_ntop`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntop) to convert IP to a string.

Comment: I need IP for client that connect to me that use getpeername()

Comment: Hmm, you're confused somewhere. accept() returns client IP and client port in its second argument. You **don't need** to call getpeername(), since that gives you same exact information.

Comment: Upvoted. I think the confusion stems from the fact that sockaddr contains the IP as 4 bytes, while the OP needs it in text.

Comment: Completely agree - there's no need to use `getpeername()` in this case, after the `accept()`, `cli_addr.sin_addr` and `cli_addr.sin_port` contain the connecting peer's address and port, in the same format that `getpeername()` returns.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this example :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

{
   int s;
   struct sockaddr_in peer;
   int peer_len;
   .
   .
   .
      /* We must put the length in a variable.              */
   peer_len = sizeof(peer);
      /* Ask getpeername to fill in peer's socket address.  */
   if (getpeername(s, &peer, &peer_len) == -1) {
      perror("getpeername() failed");
      return -1;
   }

      /* Print it. The IP address is often zero because     */
      /* sockets are seldom bound to a specific local       */
      /* interface.                                         */
   printf("Peer's IP address is: %s\n", inet_ntoa(peer.sin_addr));
   printf("Peer's port is: %d\n", (int) ntohs(peer.sin_port));
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `getpeername()` is not needed - the client address is already filled into `cli_addr` by the `accept()` call.

You only need to use `inet_ntop()`, `getnameinfo()`, or `gethostbyaddr()` to print or get more information.

Answer (score 1):

The API is described in the manual pages. You can either browse them from the console, starting with `man socket` and follow references to `man getpeername` or use Konqueror, which renders it nicely with links, if you ask for `#socket` address. In my case on Kubuntu it was necessary to install `manpages-dev` package.