# difference in address returned by getpeername() and accept() - c socket

Tags: sockets, network-programming

In server, I know the address information of local machine (AKA peer) can be attained 
by using accept method but I see some people are using getpeername() for that address after accepting the connection.

Is there any difference in result?
I saw the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104495/extract-ip-from-connection-that-listen-and-accept-in-socket-programming-in-linux).

So, I think there is no difference but I just wanted to make sure of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, just the overhead of another function call if you use getpeername instead of getting the address immediately from accept.