# accept() function fails when passing sockaddr_in

Tags: c, multithreading, network-programming, pthreads

I am writing a little server to learn about threading and also how to handle pointers with different structures and types but if I pass a sockaddr_in structure to the accept() function it fails. The program should respond to different input with the "correct/incorrect" data later to trick script kiddies and wasting their time. (I know things like inetsim already exsist but my main goal is learning with it.) But that's future music.

Inside while-loop in the main function the comment lines work (could be done better I think) but I need the sockaddr_in structure inside the threading function so I can create logfiles containing the connections ip address as its name. I created a structure with the client connection socket fd and an pointer to struct sockaddr_in so I can use it inside the threading function but like I said accept() failes with -1 all the time ending up in a segmentation fault (cause I don't catch it yet but I know I will have to later).

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h> 

#define LISTEN_BACKLOG 50
#define MAX_THREADS 100

void *handle_connection(void *args);
void *handle_connectionIP(void *args);


struct handle_connection_argument {
    int conn;
    struct sockaddr_in *peer;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[MAX_THREADS];
    int iret[MAX_THREADS];
    int conn[MAX_THREADS];
    for(int i=0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
        conn[i] = 0;
    int sock;
    char buf[1000];
    struct sockaddr_in address_info;

    struct handle_connection_argument connections[MAX_THREADS];

    address_info.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address_info.sin_port = htons(80);
    address_info.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);


    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "can not create socket\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Created socket %d\n", sock);

    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&address_info, sizeof(address_info)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "can not bind to %s\n", address_info.sin_addr.s_addr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Bind to address %s\n", "0.0.0.0");

    if(listen(sock, LISTEN_BACKLOG) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "can not listen on %s\n", "0.0.0.0");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Listening on %s\n", address_info.sin_addr.s_addr);
    int counter = 0;
    while(1){
        //conn[counter] = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
        //iret[counter] = pthread_create(&threads[counter], NULL, handle_connection, (void *)&conn[counter]);

        connections[counter].conn = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&connections[counter].peer, NULL);
        iret[counter] = pthread_create(&threads[counter], NULL, handle_connectionIP, (void *)&connections[counter]);

        counter++;
    }
    for(int i=0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)        //useless because I don't leave the while loop yet?
        pthread_join(threads[counter], NULL);

    sleep(1);
}

void *handle_connectionIP(void *args)
{
    //printf("inside thread function\n");
    int n;      // bytes received
    char *ip;   // pointer for holding ip address from connected client

    int *conn;  // socket for client connection
    struct sockaddr_in *peer;   // sockaddr_in with peer data
    struct handle_connection_argument *connection;  // argument give to handle_connectionIP function
    
    connection = (struct handle_connection_argument *)args;
    conn = &connection->conn;
    printf("%d\n", *conn);
    peer = (struct sockaddr_in*) connection->peer;
    ip = inet_ntoa(peer->sin_addr);

    char buf[1000];
    char filename[20];
    sprintf(filename, "connection%d.log", *conn);

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "w");
    //peer_address = inet_ntoa(connection->peer->sin_addr);

    printf("Connection %d from %s is managed by Thread (ID:%ld)\n", *conn, ip, pthread_self());
    while((n = recv(*conn, buf, strlen(buf)-1, 0)) > 0) {
           printf("%s", buf);
           fprintf(file, "%s", buf);
    }
    printf("Connection %d closed.\n", *conn);
    fclose(file);
}

void *handle_connection(void *args)
{
    //printf("inside thread function\n");
    int n;
    int *conn;
    conn = (int *)args;
    char buf[1000];
    char filename[20];
    sprintf(filename, "connection%d.log", *conn);

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "w");
    //peer_address = inet_ntoa(connection->peer->sin_addr);

    printf("Connection %d is managed by Thread (ID:%ld)\n", *conn, pthread_self());
    while((n = recv(*conn, buf, strlen(buf)-1, 0)) > 0) {
           printf("%s", buf);
           fprintf(file, "%s", buf);
    }

    printf("Connection %d closed.\n", *conn);
    fclose(file);
    pthread_exit((void *)pthread_self());
}
```

I tried everything with changing how I access the structure but I still don't get it.
I would appreciate any improvements and explaination what I am doing wrong here. Also improvements to the code itself (I don't mean style but maybe best practice or whats not well implemented or handled)

That is my first program with threading and networking. I just wrote simple stuff with handling files before so please don't be too hard :P

Comment: Fails how? NB The `len` parameter cannot be NULL unless the `addr` parameter is as well.

Comment: yeah i did not checked that correctly my bad. i try to figure out what the hek "socklen_t *restrict addrlen" is and how to use it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104495/extract-ip-from-connection-that-listen-and-accept-in-socket-programming-in-linux i did it just like him an now it works. thank you for bringing this to my attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing an argument that is the correct type:

```
connections[counter].conn = accept(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&connections[counter].peer,NULL);
```

`connections[counter].peer` has type `struct sockaddr_in *`, so the address of that variable has type `struct sockaddr_in **` which is not what the function is expecting.

You could pass the `peer` member directly, but that's still a problem because you have a pointer that isn't pointing anywhere.

Change the struct definition so `peer` isn't a pointer:

```
struct handle_connection_argument {
    int conn;
    struct sockaddr_in peer;
};
```

And make an associated change in your thread function:

```
peer = &connection->peer;
```

Comment: Thank you I changed it and I does not crash anymore but accept still fails and also give me a completely wrong ip address something like 65.0.64.0 what doesn't really makes sens to me. any idea why or how to debug? Im not very familliar with gdb or debugging

Comment: EDIT: user207421 brought my attention to the size of the structure for the third argument and now it works but you solution helped me with the pointer mess :D thx

Answer (score 0):

I would post this as a comment but I don't have enough rep. I'm pretty sure with `accept()`, the second argument should be the network structure you defined earlier (in this case it would be `address_info`). eg: `accept(sock, (stuct sockaddr*)&address_info, NULL);`

Hopefully this is the answer you're looking for!

Comment: referred to the manpage of accept they say "The argument addr is a pointer to a sockaddr structure.  This structure is filled in with the address of the peer socket, as known to the communications layer." address_info is holding the network information for the server i think?